# detect the submit event when click enter key

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I have one form with actually different inputs for two submit requests. When I click on any submit button I can know what action to do.
but I need to detect in which input I'm when click Enter keyboard key.

```
<form class="main-form">
  <div class="form_one">
    <input class="form_one_input" type="text" id="form_one_input"/>
    <button type="submit" class="form_one_button">Submit form one</button>
  </div>
  <div class="form_two">
    <input class="form_two_input" type="text" id="form_two_input"/>
    <button type="submit" class="form_two_button">Submit form two</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/m6433obp/

Comment: I'm not sure I quite understand what you're asking here. Could you give a little more information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To detect which input you are in use the keyup event handler as:

```
$('.form_one').bind('keyup', function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode === 13) {
    alert($(this).attr('class'));
  }
})
$('.form_two').bind('keyup', function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode === 13) {
    alert($(this).attr('class'));
  }
})
```

check demo for this [here](https://jsfiddle.net/mayank_shubham/Ljfy53tb/)

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure that I understand your question correctly. But I think that since you are using two submit buttons in the same form, you should give unique names to the buttons, so that on the server side you know that on hitting enter which input got submitted.

```
<form class="main-form">
  <div class="form_one">
    <input class="form_one_input" type="text" id="form_one_input"/>
    <button type="submit" name="first_button" class="form_one_button">Submit form one</button>
  </div>
  <div class="form_two">
    <input class="form_two_input" type="text" id="form_two_input"/>
    <button type="submit" name="second_button" class="form_two_button">Submit form two</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

And the code to check:

```
 if (isset($_POST['first_button'])) {

    } else if (isset($_POST['second_button'])) {

    } else {        
       //no button pressed
}
```

Hope this is what you were looking for.

Comment: Can i do if statement in jQuery ?? not server side